# How can I turn a string into a runnable piece of code in c#

Tags: c#, converters

In a program I'm creating, I need to be able to convert a string variable into a runnable piece of code in C#.

For example we would have

```
String code = "console.Writeline("hello");"

function(code);

double function(String var) {
     // turn var into code
     // run var
}
```

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Search for "Roslyn".

Comment: `console.Writeline` should be `Console.WriteLine` and it is a void method. Additionally, You may want to have a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304655

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lprun.exe` which comes with `LINQPad`. The [documentation](https://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx) explains the usage pretty well.

In summary you pass in your C# (also other languages available) code which is let's say stored in `Foo.txt` to the executable which is then executed.

```
lprun.exe -lang=p Foo.txt
```

`p` stands for `Program` see the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually compile the method on runtime to use them like this (ie. pass method by string and then compile it).

So for example you can:

### Create method on runtime

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

public static class RuntimeHelpers
{
    public static MethodInfo CreateFunction()
    {
        //You can pass it through parameter
        string code = @"
            using System;

            namespace RuntimeFunctions
            {                
                public class Functions
                {                
                    public static void PrintStuff(string input)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(input);
                    }
                }
            }";

        //Compile on runtime:
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(new CompilerParameters(), code);

        //Compiled code threw error? Print it.
        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            foreach (var error in results.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
            }
        }

        //Return MethodInfo for future use
        Type function = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("RuntimeFunctions.Functions");
        return function.GetMethod("PrintStuff");
    }
}
```

### Use it

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo info = RuntimeHelpers.CreateFunction();
        //Create delegate to use our function
        //If you're gonna create function that actually returns something,
        //you need to go for a Func<T, T1> cast instead of Action<T>
        var func = (Action<string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (Action<string>), info);
        func("Hello");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Loosely based on article by Lumír Kojecký on:** http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime